# Wrapping currency expression in a constant in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, format

I am learning Swift and Xcode and there is a task that I have problems wrapping my mind around.
There are three places where I use value formatter:

```
format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "PLN")
```

I packed it into a constant and it doesn't throw any errors:

```
let currencyFormatter = { (amount: Double) -> FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency in
.currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "PLN")
}
```

The execution though does throw several errors (they don't change if I swap the closure to void instead of accepting Double):

```
Text(totalPerPerson, format: currencyFormatter)
```

Some of the errors:
1.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type '((Double) -> FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency).FormatInput'
```

2. 

```
Initializer 'init(_:format:)' requires that '((Double) -> FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency).FormatInput' conform to 'Equatable'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct constant should be as

```
let currencyFormatter = FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency.currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "PLN")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is another variant of a viable answer to this question that puts greater emphasis on the type of the constant:

```
 let currencyFormatter: FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double>.Currency = .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "PLN")
```

But wouldn't find it without @Asperi's help.